javascript fetch() can hang when PHP function fails to pass echo'd values back to the ".then"
My bespoke javascript website needs to retrieve the contents of a remote json file (by name) from our server.
If the file isn't found, we need to delay 5 seconds and then retry. If the file is not found after 5 minutes  we throw an error.
This logic is needed to "catch" a json file that's being created asynchronously in the same directory by another (PHP) script.
To do this, I wrote a php script to do the polling and a javascript client function to access it.
This combination runs as expected when a fetch() is executed in the Chrome debugger console.
The content of the json file is returned without error where it can be processed.
If the named file isn't present then the check_file2.php script repeatedly looks for it until the time expires.
If the file is found during that period its contents are returned.
When run by pasting the example below into the debugger console THIS ALL WORKS AS EXPECTED.
Now the fun.
When this exact same function reference is made from within a running website script it never returns to either of the success/error handlers.
After a series of diagnostics I determined that the "echo" statement in check_file2.php executes but the echoed value never appears in the fetch().
I suspected that there was something amuck with my headers, but see nothing out of kilter.
What circumstances can cause "echo" not to return its args to the caller?
<?php // check_file.php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
// check_file.php

$filename = $_GET["filename"] ?? "";
//error_log("filename is " . $filename);
$timeout = 300; // 5 minutes
$interval = 5; // 5 seconds
function checkFile($filename)
{
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        return file_get_contents($filename);
    }
    return false;
}

$startTime = time();
$content = false;

while (time() - $startTime < $timeout) {
    $content = checkFile($filename);
    if ($content !== false) {
        error_log("Found file " . $filename); //this line appears in error_log
        echo json_encode(["success" => true, "content" => $content]); // JSON not returned
        exit();
    }
    sleep($interval);
}

echo json_encode([
    "success" => false,
    "error" => "File did not arrive within timeout period",
]);

Here's how it's called
fetch("Receipts/check_file2.php?filename="+receiptFilename)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log("got it");)
.catch(error => console.log(error));

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// I REMOVED PHP CODE AND SUBSTITUTED JAVASCRIPT POLLING AS FOLLOWS:
// Function works as expected as long as its executed from debugger console (in my case chrome).
// When example below is executed inline in my script neither .then nor .catch occurs

// found and read the file within the timer limits
function foundReceipt(data)
    {
    stripeCargo=data;
    debugger;
    }
// unable to find the file within the time limits
function failReceipt()
    {
    debugger;
    }


// polling function
async function fetchJsonWithRetry(url, maxRetryTime = 300000) {
  const startTime = Date.now();
  
  while (Date.now() - startTime < maxRetryTime) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url + "?t=" + Date.now(), {
        cache: 'no-store', // Disable caching
        headers: {
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', // older browsers
        }
      });
      
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      
      return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
    console.log("."); // every retry we drool on the console to indicate "polling"
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)); // 5 sec delay before retry
    }
  }
  
  throw new Error('Max retry time exceeded');
}

////////////////////
//Example of use:

fetchJsonWithRetry('Receipts/Receipt241029043021.json')
.then(data => {foundReceipt(data)})
.catch(error => {failReceipt()});


During all the time your PHP script is doing the polling, your JS client code sees it as a request awaiting for the server response. Maybe in the console a request timeout as long as 5 minutes is possible, whereas a regular request would time out before the PHP script finds the file. I would suggest to rather do the polling on the JS side.

Why not poll the file from the fetch instead of polling a polling php?

Also, the way your PHP is written is vulnerable. It could be used by an attacker to download any system file from the entire machine, since you place no restrictions on the path & filename being requested

Do you see the echoed response in the Network tab of DevTools?

On the recommendation of you most fine contributors I dropped the idea of having the PHP code do the looping. I now perform the loop in javascript and access the URL of the file itself, with no PHP middle-man. While it now no longer spins in PHP with a pending fetch that could take minutes to resolve, it now uses setTimeout within the javascript. This approach has it's own issue. fetch(url of the file) now returns the data if the file is found, and if the file is not found the looping begins. Issue is: when the file that was originally detected as 'absent" appears the fetch() doesn't detect it

I was able to resolve that caching issue by appending the "cache buster" suffix to the URL, like this url+"?t="+Date.now()
